# Removing specific items from ListView on Android

Tags: android, listview

I'm working on an application for Android that downloads RSS data from given URLs to a ListView where I can sort items in a number of ways (alphabetically, by date, by title etc.).

I'd like to be able to remove all items that were downloaded from a given URL.
Sorting changes original item positions, so I can't simply remove items by position.

Here I explain in detail how it's working:

1. In fragment A I have an EditText in which you type URLs.
2. Once you press ENTER:

   - the URL is passed on through an interface to fragment B where it uses the URL to download XML data and loads "item"s into it's ListView through an ArrayAdapter of 'item' class type.
   - fragment A has it's own ListView where it stores accepted URLs along with >delete< buttons next to them.

Each RSS item that's loaded into fragment's B ListView has unique title, link, and description, and publish date.

That means there are no common values in the loaded items.
I do download the "channel" part, which is the parent of all "item"s which were downloaded from the given URL, but I am not using it in the fragment's B adapter.

Here is the code for the POJO:

```
@Root(name = "rss", strict = false)
public class RSS {
    @Element
    private Channel channel;
    @Attribute
    private String version;

    public Channel getChannel() {
        return channel;
    }
}

@Root(name = "channel", strict = false)
public class Channel {
    @ElementList(name = "item", inline = true)
    List<Article> articleList;
    @Element
    private String title;
    @Element
    private String link;
    @Element
    private String description;

// setters and getters
}

@Root(name = "item", strict = false)
public class Article {
    @Element
    private String title;
    @Element
    private String description;
    @Element
    private String link;
    @Element(required = false)
    private String author;
    @Element(required = false)
    private String pubDate;

// setters and getters
}
```

This is the URL class used for storing URLs in fragment A's ListView adapter.

```
public class URL {
    private String url;

    URL(String url) {
        this.url = url;
    }
    public String getUrl() {
        return url;
    }

    public void setUrl(String title) {
        this.url = title;
    }
}
```

Now, fragment B downloads the RSS object (called 'articles' here) and this is how I load the items to the other ListView adapter:

```
previewList = articles.getChannel().articleList;
adapter.addTop(previewList);
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

And finally, the Fragment B's ListView adapter:

```
public class ArticlePreviewAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Article> {
    List<Article> articlePreviewItems;
    public ArticlePreviewAdapter(Activity activity, List<Article> articlePreviewItems) {
        super(activity, R.layout.item_article_preview, articlePreviewItems);
        this.articlePreviewItems = articlePreviewItems;
    }

    private static class ViewHolder {
        TextView articlePreviewTitle;
        TextView articlePreviewLink;
        TextView articlePreviewDescription;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder viewHolder;
        Article articlePreviewItem = getItem(position);

        if (convertView == null) {
            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_article_preview, parent, false);
            viewHolder.articlePreviewTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.articleTitle);
            viewHolder.articlePreviewLink = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.articleLink);
            viewHolder.articlePreviewDescription = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.articleDescription);
            convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
        } else {
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        viewHolder.articlePreviewTitle.setText(articlePreviewItem.getTitle());
        viewHolder.articlePreviewLink.setText(articlePreviewItem.getLink());
        viewHolder.articlePreviewDescription.setText(articlePreviewItem.getDescription());

        return convertView;
    }

    public void removeChannelItems(what do) {
            what do?
    }

    public void addTop(List<Article> articles) {
        articlePreviewItems.addAll(0, articles);
    }
}
```

Thanks for help in advance.

Comment: delete them from your dataset then `notifyDatasetChanged` on the adapter to refresh the list

Comment: The question stands how do you make an association between an URL and downloaded list items. If it was as simple as you said it, I wouldn't have posted here.

Comment: well ideally you would have a custom object that contains all the information along with the URL since your list population depends on a URL and you remove it based on that but since you gave no code on how your list is setup no real information can be provided

Comment: Updated the question with more data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your `Article` object (or `RSS`, or `Channel`) can hold references to many `URL`s, you can implement the association like below (`Article` taken as example)

```
public class URL {
    private String url;
    private ArrayList<String> articleTitles;

    public class URL(){
        this.articleTitles = new ArrayList<String>();
    }

    public void setArticleTitles(String articleTitle){
        this.articleTitle.add(articleTitle);
    }

    public ArrayList<String> getAarticleTitles(){
        return this.articleTitles;
    }

    URL(String url) {
        this.url = url;
    }
    public String getUrl() {
        return url;
    }

    public void setUrl(String title) {
        this.url = title;
    }
}
```

Then you would have your `URL` reference your object. When you delete the `URL`, you remove all `Articles` from the respective `adapter`, finally calling `notifyDataSetChanged();` on the `adapter`.

Comment: Your answer led me towards the right solution. I managed to add the URL string to every Article object. Thank you.